# RichImageField from SPFieldURL

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am currently trying to show an image from a content type field of type URL with format as "Image".

This is what i put in my aspx.

```
<wss:RichImageField id="imageCtn" runat="server" FieldName="NouvelleImgURL" />
```

How ever this does not work as sharepoint is unable to cast SPFieldUrl to type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldMultiLineText for what ever reason it needs to do this...

My Url field as its format set to "Image" inside its declaration.

I need a solution that i can put inside the aspx, it would be too easy to use code... -***_*__*_***-

Comment: I don't understand. You have a content type width field that his name "NouvelleImgURL" and his type RichImageField or what his type? And you want to display this image?

Comment: The type of the ContentType is URL, and am trying to feed it to any image holders but does not work. <asp:Image> does not have a FieldName property and RichImageField doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use RichImageField might need to change your Elements Field definition and have Type="Image".